# What is an effective way to validate a picklist field?

Tags: custom-object, validation

thank you for your time.

I have a custom object 'Work Order' with a 'Status' field that I want to create a validation function for.

I would like to show an error message if a user tries to change the status to 'Complete' if a related list object 'Purchase Order' has any records that themselves are not set to status 'Complete'.

I have attempted to create a validation rule, however I don't believe I am able to iterate through the 'Purchase Order' related list to check all are completed with that function.

If anyone has a suggestion on their preferred method for handling a case like this I would appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Purchase Order has a master-detail relationship to Work Order, you can create a Rollup Summary field on Work Order to count the number of Purchase Order records that are not Completed. From there, you can then create a validation rule like `ISPICKVAL(Status__c,'Completed') && Uncompleted_Order_Count__c > 0`. If you don't have a master-detail relationship, you can still use [DLRS](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) to calculate this for you.

Comment: I really like this answer, thank you. However I can't seem to use the Purchase Order related object with Work Order formulas at all. Purchase Order has a lookup field to Work Order which seemed to be the necessary link for other instances I've used a related object - any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: @KylanVike Are these the standard objects? If so, DLRS can help you here. Otherwise, if you can change it to Master-Detail, the Rollup Summary Field is a possibility. The field needs to be created on the Work Order (the parent object).